# Connecting a refrigerator water line - modifying the existing tubing

Tags: plumbing

I have a water line in place for the fridge but I want to modify it. It is a 1/4" copper line that runs from under my sink under the floor below the cabinets then to my fridge.  I cannot do anything to change it under there.

I have something like 10 feet of copper tubing coiled behind the fridge and I know it is going to get kinked eventually.  I would like to cut the copper tubing about two feet up from the floor and attach braided stainless steel from there.

My plan is to use a compression to thread fitting and running the flexible tubing from there. I think I would secure this connection to the wall as well so the copper and the fitting don't move too much when I slide out the fridge for cleaning.

Does anyone see any issues with this plan?

Answer (score 2):

I would install a [Ice maker outlet box](https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=ice%20maker%20outlet%20box) in the wall. This makes a nice clean looking install that is flush with the wall and does not interfere with getting the fridge in place.

It is like a washing machine valve box but with just one 1/4 turn valve that will except the stainless steel braided line. The braided line screws onto the valve and then onto the tube in the back of your refrigerator.

There are few different kind of connection types available, Copper sweat, Pex crimp and push to connect.

You will need to transition from your 1/4 copper to whatever type connection the box is that you choose.

[image]

Comment: Jeez, why isn't this standard in all construction.  Seems only reasonable instead of having loops of copper pipe.  I'll take a look at these.  Thank you.